# Associating og:video tag with video uploaded natively to Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta

Since Facebook is no longer permitting inline playback for third party players ([source](https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007867647-Optimizing-your-website-for-posting-to-social-platforms)), is it possible to link a native Facebook video to your website's og:video meta tags?

My goal is to set it up so that when others share my website link, a video appears when that link appears in the news feed, similar to some sponsored posts:

[image]

I am hoping that if I can associate a natively uploaded Facebook video with `og:video`, it will work, but I am not sure how to actually find the link to those video files. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm.. interesting..